# Risc-V extension for dismissible loads

Tags: cpu-architecture, riscv

Certain architectures have "dismissible loads" in addition to normal loads: when the load is denied, instead of issuing an exception (leading to a segmentation fault), a default value (e.g., zero) is written to the destination register. This allows the compiler to move loads before a conditional branch, which may be important for performance on non speculative cores.

I was wondering if there was a Risc-V extension for this. I haven't found any.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for dismissible loads (i.e. load instructions that do not trap based on the memory protections of a memory location, when a standard lw, lh, lb etc. would trap) among the current set of complete standard RISC-V extensions. They wouldn't fit naturally in any of the planned standard extensions either. You can find the current version of the ISA specification [here](https://riscv.org/technical/specifications/). (Standard extensions are designed and approved by the RISC-V foundation, are guaranteed not to conflict with each other, and will appear in the ISA specification).

That being said, RISC-V was designed to make it straightforward to design and implement non-standard extensions for custom accelerators. There are certain bits reserved for the implementation of custom extensions, with a guarantee that current and future standard extensions will not conflict. So there's also nothing in place to prevent adding a dismissible load instruction to RISC-V as part of a non-standard extension.